# split output file into different sub files

Tags: linux, shell, split

I have a output file having data as :

```
 -> Added to botcc.rules (2)

 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"testing rule 1";sid:1323;rev:1;)

 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"testing rule 2";sid:1323;rev:1;)

 -> Added to compromised.rules (1)

 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"testing rule for comp";sid:1323;rev:1;)
```

I need shell script which should split the above output in different sub-files with their names as `botcc.rules`,`compromised.rules` having their respective rules(below data).

Answer (score 0):

The solution using powerful `awk` language:
We'll split the input file into multiple files at every occurrence of pattern `> Added to`. But the line containing the pattern should not be in the new files.

```
awk '/> Added to/{ x=$4;next }{ print > x }' inputfile
```

This command contains 2 sets of curly braces: 
The control goes to the first set of braces only on encountering a line containing the pattern `> Added to`. Due to the `next` command, the lines containing the `> Added to` enters the first curly braces and then starts reading the next line immediately due to the `next` command. As a result, the `> Added to` lines does not get to the second curly braces and hence the `> Added to` does not appear in the split files. 
The second set will be encountered by every line since there is no condition and hence always true.

`x=$4` - `x` variable is assigned with the fourth field value `$4`(" "(space) is the default *awk* field separator, therefore, the 4th field will contain a file name e.g. `botcc.rules`)

---

Output for `botcc.rules` contents:

```
$ cat botcc.rules
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"testing rule 1";sid:1323;rev:1;)

alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"testing rule 2";sid:1323;rev:1;)
```

---

Output for `compromised.rules` contents:

```
$ cat compromised.rules

alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"testing rule for comp";sid:1323;rev:1;)
```